# Solrnet equivalent for frange in a facet query for Distance

Tags: solr, spatial, solrnet, spatial-query

I have implemented Spatial Search and need to generate facets for ranges or 'buckets' of distance in Solr: the following link helped me here - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#How_to_facet_by_distance

I found the solution to the following question 
[Faceting on distance in solr- how to generate links that search withing a given range of distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035270/faceting-on-distance-in-solr-how-to-generate-links-that-search-withing-a-given) helpful.

I am using Solrnet to generate Solr queries from my .NET based site. I cant find a link that would help me to generate a frange part (*italicized*) of the query as below. Please help in pointing me to the code to generate this using solrnet.

&q=*:*&sfield=store&pt=45.15,-93.85**&facet.query={!frange l=0 u=5}geodist()&facet.query={!frange l=5.001 u=3000}geodist()**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are already using `ExtraParams` to set the sField & pt parameters. You should be able to add the facet.query parameters to this as well.

```
var results = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All, new QueryOptions
{
    ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "sfield", "store" } , 
                { "pt", "45.15,-93.85" }
                { "facet.query", "{!frange l=0 u=5}geodist()" } ,
                { "facet.query", "{!frange l=5.001 u=3000}geodist()" } ,
            }
 });

return results;
```

Additionally, you might be able to use `SolrFacetQuery` combined with `LocalParams` to build the facet queries. Check the following links for some examples:

- https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Facets
- [How to add Spatial Solr to a Solrnet query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788450/how-to-add-spatial-solr-to-a-solrnet-query)

**Update:**
As stated in the comments, the use of the `ExtraParams` does not work because it is a dictionary object and as a result does not allow for multiple facet.query parameters. However, I was able to use the Facet Queries as described in the SolrNet Facet Wiki page linked above to create the following:

```
var facet1 = new SolrFacetQuery(new SolrQuery("{!frange l=0 u=5}geodist()}"));
var facet2 = new SolrFacetQuery(new SolrQuery("{!frange l=5.001 u=3000}geodist()}"));
var results = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All, new QueryOptions
    {
        ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"sfield", "store"},
                {"pt", "45.15,-93.85"}
            },
        Facet = new FacetParameters
            {
                Queries = new[]
                    {
                        facet1, facet2
                    }
            }
    });
return results;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Paige. Since the ExtraParams and the LocalParams are dictionary objects, I am unable to pass the facet.query twice. I tried this earlier :(. I tried SolrQueryByRange too which is generating the range in the form of 1 TO 5 which does not work with Solr. Any further pointers pls.

Comment: Are those facet.query parameters the same all the time? You may be able to specify them right on the request handlers on the Solr side in the defaults section. That's a workaround to the duplicate facet.query issues.

Comment: I just worked out a sample locally and updated my answer. This appears to be sending the correct request to Solr.